Using UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK to prevent duplicate data from being inserted
I have a service method (C#) that retrieves data from an Azure SQL Server database, processes it, and then performs some inserts. When this method is called from different processes, for a large amount of data, I sometimes get duplicate rows, same data being inserted multiple times.
The code is something like this:
begin transaction 

if ((select count(*) 
     from TableA with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
     where col1 = @col1) > @count)
 begin
     select 0
     rollback
     return;
 end

 insert into TableA (col1, col2) values (@col1, @col2)
 select 1
 
 commit; 

I do a count after I read the data and before starting to process it to check if new rows were inserted. I assumed using (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) on the table will stop other transactions from reading the data. When I debug it this is what I see but when running for multiple values for col1 I still get duplicates.
How can I prevent other transaction from inserting data?
Edit: the value of @count will always be > 0. Just to be clear, in TableA I will have multiple values for col1 but col2 will be different, col2 is the ID of another column. That's why I am doing the count, to check if it changed since I've read the data.

What is the value of @count? It would seem you want to accept a certain amount of duplication if that is greater than 0. If it is 0 then why not just use IF EXISTS? Side note: you are missing a commit; just before that return; in the if.

Why do an IF at all? Why not just it an EXISTS in the WHERE for the INSERT?

I've updated the description, thank you. The value of @count will always be > 0

So obviously you are going to have duplicates over col1, what else would you expect? That is exactly what you've asked it. Are you sure you didn't mean if exists (select 1 from TableA with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) where col1 = @col1)
